# Can I view intermediate results of lexer and parser in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, cpython, lexer

With the release of Python 3.9, which changed the parser from an LL(1) parser to a PEG-based parser, it got me thinking that I've never seen the lexer or parser for Python (CPython). As I understand it the picture looks like

```
source -> lexer -> TOKENS
TOKENS -> parser -> AST
AST -> ??? -> pyc file
```

Is it possible to view these intermediate results (TOKENS, AST, any others I missed)?

Comment: You can use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ast.parse(some_string)` will give you the ast tree.  You can then use various methods in the module to print it out or examine it programmatically.

Comment: Any ideas about the lexer's output?

Comment: I see this documentation.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html.   I've never used it, so I don't know much about it.